# Prove that $p_{1} = p_{2}$ and $n_{1} = n_{2}$ in $W^⊥$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

> Let $W$ be a subspace of $ℝ^n$. Let $v\in ℝ^n$. Suppose $p_{1}, p_2 \in W$ and $n_{1}, n_{2}\in W^⊥$ are such that $w = p_{1} + n_{1} = p_{2} + n_{2}$. Prove that $p_{1} = p_{2}$ and $n_{1} = n_{2}$.

I know that $W^⊥$ can be defined as $\{u\in ℝ^n: \text{ for all } v\in V, u \cdot v = 0\}$. 
That's all i know as i am basically stuck, because there are no direction for me to address this question.

Is $p$ referring to projection vector and $n$ being orthogonal to $p$? Even if it's the case that $n \cdot p = 0$, how does that link in helping me to tackle this question?

Many thanks.

Comment: $p_1-p_2=n_2-n_1$ is in both $W$ and $W^{\perp}$. Does this help?

Comment: @user340297 Mind explaining the concepts asked in this question?

Comment: You got that $n$ and $p$ are orthogonal to each other. This decomposition is fairly basic fact about finite dimensional vector spaces using basis argument. Then think about my previous comment. What kind of vectors are in both $W$ and its orthogonal complement?